# how to remove specific element when parent has an element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

this is my code:

```js
jQuery('.page-id-9 .woocommerce td.tdclass :not(.variation)').remove();
```

```css
td{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="page-id-9">
<table class="woocommerce">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="tdclass">#1</td>
        <td class="tdclass"><span class="other_item">wallet</span></td>
        <td class="tdclass">$45</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tdclass">#2</td>
        <td class="tdclass">
            <dl class="variation">
                <dt class="variation-">Select Category :</dt>
                    <dd class="variation-"><p>Category 1</p></dd>
                <dt class="variation-">Select Product :</dt>
                    <dd class="variation-"><p>product 1</p></dd>
                <dt class="variation-">Link :</dt>
                    <dd class="variation-"><p><a href="#" rel="nofollow">Link</a></p></dd>      
            </dl>
            <span class="other_item">wallet2</span>
        </td>
        <td class="tdclass">$35</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

I want to check if td element has dl class="variation" then remove "other_item" tag.

in my code, wallet2 Should be removed. But all elements have been removed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `has()` method (or `:has()` selector) to filter the ones where the desired class exists and then `find()` to remove the other span

```
jQuery('.page-id-9 .woocommerce td.tdclass')
        .has('dl.variation')
        .find('.other_item')
        .remove();
```

Or perhaps simpler, target the variation class and use `siblings()`

```
jQuery('.page-id-9 .woocommerce td.tdclass dl.variation')
         .siblings('.other_item')
         .remove();
```

---

Example using `has()`

```js
jQuery('.page-id-9 .woocommerce td.tdclass')
        .has('dl.variation')
        .find('.other_item')
        .remove();
```

```css
td{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="page-id-9">
<table class="woocommerce">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="tdclass">#1</td>
        <td class="tdclass"><span class="other_item">wallet</span></td>
        <td class="tdclass">$45</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="tdclass">#2</td>
        <td class="tdclass">
            <dl class="variation">
                <dt class="variation-">Select Category :</dt>
                    <dd class="variation-"><p>Category 1</p></dd>
                <dt class="variation-">Select Product :</dt>
                    <dd class="variation-"><p>product 1</p></dd>
                <dt class="variation-">Link :</dt>
                    <dd class="variation-"><p><a href="#" rel="nofollow">Link</a></p></dd>      
            </dl>
            <span class="other_item">wallet2</span>
        </td>
        <td class="tdclass">$35</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
```